# Want to make sure object not in queryset before adding it

Tags: django, django-models

My "Event" object has a "Name" field. There is the possibility that the name is wrong, so a user may suggest a new name. That name gets put into the event's "suggestedN" list. However, I don't want there to be duplicates of one suggestion in that list. I felt like this was a straightforward problem, but for some reason am not finding much success.

Here is how my view currently looks:

```
@login_required
def suggestName(request):
    name = request.POST['name'].strip()
        event_id = request.POST['event_id']
    try:
        e = Event.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        e = customEvent.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
    if name in e.suggestedN.all():
        pass
    else:
        (some code)
```

Is my `if name in e.suggestedN.all()` statement wrong?

Here's a brief view of my Event's model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    suggestedN = models.ManyToManyField('suggestedName', blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')


class suggestedName(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Comment: sorry, deleted my answer since I mistakenly confused that customEvent with the suggestedName class, thus providing you with an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the name attribute on m2m not the m2m itself to compare

```
@login_required
def suggestName(request):
    name = request.POST['name'].strip()
        event_id = request.POST['event_id']
    try:
        e = Event.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        e = customEvent.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
    if name in e.suggestedN.values_list('name', flat=True):
        pass
    else:
        (some code)
```